# Cannot set property 'innerText' of null, when trying to write data from firebase to header element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

New to React, getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null

When trying to write data from firebase to a header.

```
export default function Deposits() {
 const classes = useStyles();

 const preName = document.getElementById("userNm");

 const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');
 const dbNameObject = dbRefObject.child('name');

 dbRefObject.on('value', snap=> {preName.innerText = 
 JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null)});
 dbNameObject.on('child_added', snap => console.log(snap.val()));



 return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <h2 id="userNm"> </h2>
    <Typography id="number"  variant="h4"style={{textAlign: "center",}}>
     NUMBER HERE
    </Typography>
    <Typography id="grade" className={classes.depositContext} style= 
      {{textAlign: "center",}}>
       GRADE HERE
    </Typography>

</React.Fragment>
);
}
```

Expected the name under "name" from my firebase DB to be displayed as the header, but it's blank.

Comment: With React, you're supposed to use `<h2>{this.state.name}</h2>` then use `this.setState({ name: some_value });` or the hooks equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply access element with `getElementById` in React. You need to use `React.createRef()`.

```js
const preName = React.createRef();
const dbNameObject = dbRefObject.child('name');
dbRefObject.on('value', snap=> {preName.current.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null)});

return (
  ...
  <h2 ref={preName}> </h2>
  ...
)
```

But I suggest you use `state` instead of Ref.

Comment: You're a champion :) Thank you, I had been stuck on this for a while.